# filter data in rest api monngodb node express

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, filter

I am creating my first rest api and i have done the findbyId,find,delete,update part. Now i need to filter out data i have searched out methods for it but i can't understand them. Question: i have programs collection and it has discipline field i want to filter out results based on name of the discipline. here is my code

```
app.get('/api/programs/', function(req,res)
{
    disc = req.query.discipline;
    console.log(disc)
    //by query parameter
    Programs.find({where : { _discipline: disc }},function(err,progData)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(progData);
    } );
```

url:
http://localhost:3000/api/programs/?discipline=Engineering

program schema:

```
var progSchema = mongoose.Schema
({
   uni_name:       String,
   program_name:   String,
   degree_name:    String,
   duration:       String,
   fee_per_year:   String,
   admission_date: String,
   last_merit:     String,
   discipline:     String,
   About_Disc:     String
});
```

this code is not working it returns empty [],but database contains the required data.
if you have better solution please suggest.

Comment: Can you please include the `Programs` schema in your question.

Comment: schema added @Chaitanya

Comment: Okay, so there is no need of where in mongodb. You need to change your query to Programs.find({ discipline: disc }, function (err, progData) { body });  I guess this will work for you.

Comment: i did it but still gettting empty[] , i don't know why, although discipline=Engineering exists in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it 
need to add the collection name as

```
var progSchema = mongoose.Schema
({
   uni_name:       String,
   program_name:   String,
   degree_name:    String,
   duration:       String,
   fee_per_year:   String,
   admission_date: String,
   last_merit:     String,
   discipline:     String,
   About_Disc:     String
},
{ collection: "Engineering" }
);
```